# PHP: How to get title and description Google Book Api?

Tags: php, api, google-api

I have this code but it doesn't work. It show nothing.

```
<?php 
$item = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Bowling Alone&maxResults=1');

$booktitle = (isset($item->volumeInfo->title) ? $item->volumeInfo->title : false);
$description = (isset($item->volumeInfo->description) ? $item->volumeInfo->description : false);

echo "<b>Title:</b> " . $booktitle;
echo "<b>Description:</b> " . $description;
?>
```

So, please help me fix it ! Also, this is any way to get content faster ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Nobody can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$item = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Bowling%20Alone&maxResults=1');
$item = json_decode($item);
$item = reset($item->items);

$booktitle = (isset($item->volumesInfo->title) ? $item->volumeInfo->title : false);
$description = (isset($item->volumeInfo->description) ? $item->volumeInfo->description : false);

echo "<b>Title:</b> " . $booktitle;
echo "<b>Description:</b> " . $description;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make it url compatible, so no spaces in it. You also needed to add a foreach loop because incase of more results. And decode the json result into a object

```
$item = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Bowling%20Alone&maxResults=1');
$item = json_decode($item);

foreach ($item->items as $item) {
    $booktitle = (isset($item->volumesInfo->title) ? $item->volumeInfo->title : false);
    $description = (isset($item->volumeInfo->description) ? $item->volumeInfo->description : false);
    echo "<b>Title:</b> " . $booktitle;
    echo "<b>Description:</b> " . $description;
}
```

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work for me. Also, I only want to get content first book.

Comment: Add a reset to the array

Comment: How do I get Authors? It's not similar to the Title